# Prove that if $b\in B$ is the infimum of $B,$ then $b$ is the minimum of $B$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, upper-lower-bounds

Let $(A,\le)$ be an ordered set and $B\subset A$. Prove that if $b\in B$ is the infimum of $B$ then $b$ is the minimum of $B$.

Proof

I want to show that $\forall x\in B, b\le x.$

Suppose $b$ is the infimum of $B$.

$\implies$ $b$ is the maximum of all the lower bounds  of $B$.

$\implies \forall y\in A: y\le b,$ where each $y$ is a lower bound of $B$.

From here, how do I relate $b\le x$ with $y\le b$?

What can I do now to continue the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things. Since $b$ is an infimum of $B$, it is a lower bound of $B$. What it means to be a lower bound of $B$ is precisely that $b \le x$ for all $x \in B$. Since $b \in B$, you have your desired result!

Comment: this $\le$ is just a notation in this context, do you think it is a good idea to relation it with the usual meaning of it?, for example $3\le 4$

Comment: @Isabella: I understand what $\le$ means. The definition of what it means for $b$ to be an infimum of $B$ (relative to whatever order relation $\le$ refers to) includes that $b \le x$ for all $x \in A$. (See the second half of Definition 5.2.10 [here](http://math.cmu.edu/~cnewstea/book/infdesc.pdf), for example.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose on contrary that $b$ is not minimum. Then, by definition there is an $x\in B$ such that $x<b$. But, for all $y\in B$ we have that $b\leq y$, since $b$ is the infimum of $B$. In particular, $b\leq x$. But this contradicts that $x<b$. Thus, $b$ is minimum.

Comment: "[...] for all $y\in B$ we have that $b\leq y$, since $b$ is the infimum of $B$" <-- this is enough on its own, the contradiction padding either side isn't necessary! :P